# How to continue parsing after an error in JXBI to collect all JAXB Unmarshalling error till end of the xml file

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb, unmarshalling

For Sample I have below xml and xsd.

When I am trying to parse below xml I am expecting JAXB parser should parse till end of the file and get all error in once.

**XML Which is having multiple error as below :** It has missing closing tag of   `</purchasedOn` and `</itemName`.

If my input xml is having multiple error it will throw exception and stop parsing when it JXBI parser encounter first error.

**My question here is : Is there any way to continue parsing using JAXB for any input xml even after encountering first error expecting more error to collect all error till end of the file**

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
     - with linked exception:
    [org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 11; columnNumber: 7; The end-tag for element type "purchasedOn" must end with a '>' delimiter.]
        at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:335)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:563)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:249)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:214)
        at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:157)
        at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:204)
        at com.user.ezpense.processor.JAXBProcessor.main(JAXBProcessor.java:36)
    Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 11; columnNumber: 7; The end-tag for element type "purchasedOn" must end with a '>' delimiter.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
```

**Erroneous input xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <expenseReport>
      <user>
        <userName>Sanaulla</userName>
      </user>
      <items>
        <item>
          <itemName>Seagate External HDD</itemName>
          <purchasedOn>August 24, 2010</purchasedOn
          <amount>6776.5</amount>
        </item>
        <item>
          <itemName>Benq HD Monitor</itemName
          <purchasedOn>August 24, 2012</purchasedOn>
          <amount>15000</amount>
        </item>
      </items>
    </expenseReport>
```

**xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="expenseReport" type="ExpenseT" />
  <xs:complexType name="ExpenseT">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="user" type="UserT" />
      <xs:element name="items" type="ItemListT" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="UserT">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="userName" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="ItemListT">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="item" type="ItemT" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="ItemT">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="itemName" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="purchasedOn" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="amount" type="xs:decimal" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

**Correct XML expense.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<x:catalog xmlns:x="urn:books">
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications with
      XML.</description>
   </book>
</x:catalog>
```

Java code that i have written for parsing input xml using JAXB : 
**Java parsing code:**

```
package com.user.ezpense.processor;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

import com.user.ezpense.report.jaxb.ExpenseT;
import com.user.ezpense.report.jaxb.ItemListT;
import com.user.ezpense.report.jaxb.ItemT;
import com.user.ezpense.report.jaxb.ObjectFactory;
import com.user.ezpense.report.jaxb.UserT;

public class JAXBProcessor {

  /**
   * @param args
   * @throws JAXBException 
 * @throws FileNotFoundException 
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException, FileNotFoundException {
    //1. We need to create JAXContext instance
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class);

    //2. Use JAXBContext instance to create the Unmarshaller.
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

    //3. Use the Unmarshaller to unmarshal the XML document to get an instance of JAXBElement.
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("expense.xml"));

    JAXBElement<ExpenseT> unmarshalledObject = 
        (JAXBElement<ExpenseT>)unmarshaller.unmarshal(in);

    //4. Get the instance of the required JAXB Root Class from the JAXBElement.
    ExpenseT expenseObj = unmarshalledObject.getValue();
    UserT user = expenseObj.getUser();
    ItemListT items = expenseObj.getItems();

    //Obtaining all the required data from the JAXB Root class instance.
    System.out.println("Printing the Expense for: "+user.getUserName());
    for ( ItemT item : items.getItem()){
      System.out.println("Name: "+item.getItemName());
      System.out.println("Value: "+item.getAmount());
      System.out.println("Date of Purchase: "+item.getPurchasedOn());
    }   
  }

}
```

Comment: Why do you bother parsing an illegal XML? Why not simply correct it, or ask the creator to correct it?

Comment: can you try removing spaces in the value and see if the problem is resolved

Comment: My requirement is  my services will be called from client and they will invoke with xml request. 
At response either I need to give success response  or  need to give all the problem or error occurred with in once.

Comment: @ Seelenvirtuose
Above services  is going paid services to the client. So each invoke service  will be charge minimal amount, In this case if we give all error in once then multiple call of services can be avoid.
Client are asking to return all the error in once failure response.